# Roslyn - Find implementation of abstract method

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have several classes that inherit from the same base class. In the base class there is an abstract method that is implemented in the derived classes.

How can I find all implementations of the abstract method in the derived classes? I cannot use SymbolFinder.FindImplementationsAsync, because I don't have a Solution object (only models in a compilation). I prefer to not create a Solution object if not strictly needed.

Comment: Do you already have the classes that extend the base class?

Comment: No, that's the difficulty. When I have a derived class, it's very easy to know the base class. But not vice versa.

Comment: You can go through the `semanticModel.Compilation.GlobalNamespace` to get all named types in a given project (compilation). You might want to have a look here to do this: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/blob/63c661bde321a96ffcf9daca1aabac79e0f37929/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/src/SonarAnalyzer.Common/Helpers/SymbolHelper.cs#L30. For each named type you can find base class, and then check the methods. If you're inside Visual Studio, and the analyzer only need to work inside a VSIX, then you can get the `VisualStudioWorkspace` and from there you can get a reference to the solution.